# MySQL Query COUNTing incorrectly

Tags: mysql

Well, I realise that in fact it's more likely to be my logic that's counting wrong ;)

So here's my query:

```
SELECT 
  code.id AS codeid, code.title AS codetitle, code.summary AS codesummary, code.author AS codeauthor, code.date,
  code_tags.*, 
  tags.*, 
  users.firstname AS authorname, 
  users.id AS authorid,
  ratingItems.*, FORMAT((ratingItems.totalPoints / ratingItems.totalVotes), 1) AS rating,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ', ') AS taggroup,
  COUNT(comments.codeid) AS commentcount
FROM 
  code
  join code_tags on code_tags.code_id = code.id
  join tags on tags.id = code_tags.tag_id
  join users on users.id = code.author
  left join comments on comments.codeid = code.id
  left join ratingItems on uniqueName = code.id
GROUP BY code_id
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Sorry there's quite a bit of 'bloat' in that. The problem I'm having is with `commentcount` or (`COUNT(comments.codeid) AS commentcount`) - I want to count the total number of comments a code submission has. Previously, it was working correctly but I restructured my MySQL syntax and now it's stopped working :(

There's only 2 `code` submissions in the database that have comments. The first of these results that is returned correctly identifies it has more than 0 comments, but reports it as having '2' in `commentcount`, when in fact it has only 1.

The second submission **ALSO** only has one comment, but, it tells me that it has 4!

Can someone tell me what's wrong my logic here?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: What is code_id?  I see code.id and codeid, but I don't see where code_id originates.

Comment: I'm guessing that the one that is showing as having 2 comments has 2 tags, and the one that is showing as 4 comments has 4 tags. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT comments.codeid) AS commentcount
```

or

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.codeid = code.id) AS commentcount
```

Answer (score 1):

Try eliminating the GROUP BY constraint.  Then see where your duplicate rows are coming from, and fix your original query.  This will fix your COUNTs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with a simple query, and building up from that.  If I have understood your structure correctly, the following query will return the correct number of comments for each code submission:

```
SELECT code.*, COUNT(code.id) AS comment_count
FROM code
JOIN comments ON comments.codeid = code.id
GROUP BY(code.id);
```

There's a few odd looking column names and joins in your example, which may be contributing to the problem … or it might just be an odd naming scheme :-)

For example, you are joining `ratingItems` to `code` by comparing `code.id` with `ratingItems.uniqueName`.  That might be correct, but it doesn't quite look right.  Perhaps it should be more like:

```
LEFT JOIN ratingItems ON ratingItems.code_id = code.id
```

Start with a basic working query, then add the other joins.